# Show $\lim_{m \to \infty} \sup_{n \ge 0} E \left[ e^{-X_n} \sum_{k>m} \frac{X_n^k}{k!} \right]=0$ for a sequence of positive r.v.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\{ X_n \}_{n \ge 0} $ be some  sequence  of non-negative radon variables.    How to show the following limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{m \to \infty} \sup_{n \ge 0} E  \left[  e^{-X_n} \sum_{k>m} \frac{X_n^k}{k!} \right]=0. 
\end{align}

Clearly, we have that $e^{-X_n} \sum_{k>m} \frac{X_n^k}{k!} \le e^{-X_n}  e^{X_n} =1$, so if we didn't have a $\sup$ in the expression, then the result would follow by the dominated convergence theorem.

So,  it seems that we have to argue and get rid of the supremum.  This is the part of the problem that I am not sure how to do.

Comment: can you explain what the supremum means exactly? Since I don't see what set we're dealing with...

Comment: @BelowAverageIntelligence  The supremum is over the index of the sequence of random variables. To be more specific, we have a sequence of random variables  $X_1,X_2,...$.   For each random variables we evaluate the expected the expectation $f(n,t)=E[e^{-X_n} \sum_{k>m} \frac{X_n^k}{k!}]$  and then take the sup over the index $n$  $\sup_{n \ge 0} f(n,m)$. So whole expression can be written as $\lim_{m \to \infty} \sup_{n \ge 0} f(n,m)$.

Comment: Will taking the $\sup_n$ into the expectation so that it becomes larger help? Do we then have that the limit as $m\to\infty $ of $\sup_n$ of the expression inside the expectation tending to zero? Just some thoughts...

Comment: Without extra assumption on $X_n$, your limit need not be zero. For instance, we have $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n = \infty \quad \text{a.s.} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{n\geq 0}\mathbb{E} \left[ e^{-X_n}\sum_{k>m}^{\infty} \frac{X_n^k}{k!} \right] = 1. $$

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you for this example. Would an assumption that $\sup_{n}E[X_n] <\infty$ fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is not true that 
$$
\begin{align}\tag{*}
\lim_{m \to \infty} \sup_{n \ge 0} \mathbb E  \left[  e^{-X_n} \sum_{k>m} \frac{X_n^k}{k!} \right]=0. 
\end{align}
$$
For example, when $X_n$ is constant equal to $x_n$ and $x_n\to +\infty$, then 
$$
e^{-x_n}\sum_{k\gt m}\frac{x_n^k}{k!}=1-e^{-x_n}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{x_n^k}{k!}
$$
hence for all fixed $m$, 
$$
\sup_{n\geqslant 1}e^{-x_n}\sum_{k\gt m}\frac{x_n^k}{k!}=1.
$$
In fact, a necessary and sufficient condition for (*) to hold is 
$$
\lim_{R\to \infty}\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\Pr\left\{X_n\gt R\right\}=0,\tag{**}
$$
which is usually referred as tightness.
Indeed, if $(**)$ holds, then for all fixed $R$, 
$$
\mathbb E  \left[  e^{-X_n} \sum_{k>m} \frac{X_n^k}{k!} \right]=\mathbb E  \left[  e^{-X_n} \sum_{k>m} \frac{X_n^k}{k!}\mathbf 1\left\{X_n\leqslant  R\right\} \right]+\mathbb E  \left[  e^{-X_n} \sum_{k>m} \frac{X_n^k}{k!}\mathbf 1\left\{X_n\gt  R\right\} \right].
$$
The first term of the right hand side is bounded by $$\sup_{0\leqslant t\leqslant R}e^{-t}\sum_{k\gt m}\frac{t^k}{k!}\leqslant\sum_{k\gt m}\frac{R^k}{k!} $$
and for the second term, using the fact that $e^{-t}\sum_{k\gt m}\frac{t^k}{k!}\leqslant 1$, we get
$$
\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\mathbb E  \left[  e^{-X_n} \sum_{k>m} \frac{X_n^k}{k!} \right]
\leqslant\sum_{k\gt m}\frac{R^k}{k!}+\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\Pr\left\{X_n\gt R\right\}.
$$
For the opposite direction, we use non-decreasingness of the function $t\mapsto e^{-t}\sum_{k\gt m}t^k/k!$, we get 
$$
\sup_{n \ge 0} \mathbb E  \left[  e^{-X_n} \sum_{k>m} \frac{X_n^k}{k!} \right]
\geqslant \sup_{n \ge 0} \mathbb E  \left[  e^{-X_n} \sum_{k>m} \frac{X_n^k}{k!}\mathbf 1\left\{X_n\gt  R\right\}  \right]\geqslant e^{-R} \sum_{k>m} \frac{R^k}{k!} \sup_{n \ge 0} \Pr\left\{X_n\gt R\right\}
$$
hence 
$$
\sup_{n \ge 0} \Pr\left\{X_n\gt R\right\}\leqslant \left(e^{-R} \sum_{k>m} \frac{R^k}{k!} \right)^{-1}\sup_{n \ge 0} \mathbb E  \left[  e^{-X_n} \sum_{k>m} \frac{X_n^k}{k!} \right].
$$
Taking the $\limsup$ as $R$ is going to infinity and using the fact that forall fixed $m$, $e^{-R} \sum_{k>m} \frac{R^k}{k!} \to 1$, we establish (**).